impossible to retrieve the table ID in the URL
I have this management rule: A Commercial Proposal can contain One or more products and A product can be contained in one or more Commercial Proposals and in the commercial proposal details I wish to edit the product associated with this proposal.
here is my table allowing me to register a product to associate with a commercial proposal:
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('propo_com_produits', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('propo_com_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('produit_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('service_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('tva')->nullable();
            $table->string('prix_unitaire_ht')->nullable();
            $table->string('quantite')->nullable();
            $table->string('reduction')->nullable();
            $table->string('prix_revient')->nullable();
            $table->string('total_ht')->nullable();
            $table->string('date_prevue_mis_en_service')->nullable();
            $table->string('date_prevue_fin')->nullable();
            $table->string('user_created_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('user_updated_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

my Commercial Proposal Model
public function propoCom_produit()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PropoCom_produit::class);
    }

my Product model Associated with the commercial proposal
public function proposition (){
        return $this->belongsTo(PropoCom::class,"propo_com_id");
    }

then here is my controller method allowing me to display the details of the commercial proposal and also allowing me to edit the product associated with the commercial proposal:
public function show($id)
    {
        $propositions = PropoCom::findOrfail($id);
        $produits = Produit::where('etat_vente', 1)->get();
        $services = Service::where('etat', 1)->get();
        $newproposition = PropoCom::with('produits')->findOrFail($id);
        $newservice = PropoCom::with('services')->findOrFail($id);

        //$editpropo = PropoCom::with('propoCom_produit')->findOrFail($id);

        $commerce = $propositions->commerce;

        return view('layouts.commerce.details-propo-brouillon', compact('propositions', 'produits', 'newproposition', 'services', 'newservice', 'commerce'));
    }

my other method allowing me to call the edit form to edit the product associated with the proposal:
public function edit($id)
    {
        $propoproduit = PropoCom_produit::findOrfail($id);
        $proposition = $propoproduit->proposition;
        return view('layouts.commerce.edit-propo', compact('propoproduit', 'proposition'));
    } 

my editing route for the product associated with the commercial proposal:
Route::get('/commerce/new/proposition/details/{propo_com_produit_id}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\PropositionController::class, 'edit'])->name('proposition.produit.edit');

and my blade view:
@foreach($newproposition->produits as $produit)
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th scope="row">{{ $produit->libelle }}</th>
                                                                    <td>{{ $produit->pivot->tva }}%</td>
                                                                    <td>{{ number_format($produit->pivot->prix_unitaire_ht, 0, ',', ' ') }}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{ $produit->pivot->quantite }}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{ number_format($produit->pivot->reduction, 0, ',', ' ' )}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{ number_format($produit->prix_revient, 0, ',', ' ') }}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{ number_format(($produit->pivot->quantite * $produit->pivot->prix_unitaire_ht) -  $produit->pivot->reduction, 0, ',', ' ')}}</td>
                                                                    @if($propositions->etat != 1 && $propositions->etat != 2 && $propositions->etat != 3 && $propositions->etat != 4)
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a href="{{ route('proposition.produit.edit', $produit->id) }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></a>
                                                                            <form onsubmit="return DeleteCinfirm('')" action="" method="POST">
                                                                                @csrf
                                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                                                                            </form>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    @endif
                                                                </tr> 
                                                            @endforeach

but in the edit URL it retrieves the product Id (produit_id) from the table or I want to edit the Id (propo_com_produit_id). anyone have an idea please ?

It sounds like you're inadvertently passing the produit_id (the product's ID) to a route that expects the propo_com_produit_id (the ID of the record associating the product with the commercial proposal)
it is passing product id because in your balde your foreach is like: @foreach($newproposition->produits as $produit)
shouldn't it be
@foreach($newproposition->propoCom_produit as $item)
and then to get your fileds you may use: $item->produit->libelle or $item->id which will be the propo_com_produit_id

It works but I can't get the product name? an idea ?

whats the variable of product name? try to dd($item->produit)

in my propo_com_produits table I retrieved the product ID and the details of the commercial proposal I retrieved as follows: {{ $product->libelle }} but when I modified the foreach by @foreach($newproposition ->propoCom_product as $product) the wording has disappeared
